# chrome.desktopcapture.choosedesktopmedia can only be used in extention

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension

Hi I am new to node js server application, and just wnat to know if chrome.desktopcapture.choosedesktopmedia can only be used in chrome extention?

I am trying to make this work as a server page hosted on node js.
Note: This works when used inside chrome exteiontion but the same code used when hosted on server gives error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chooseDesktopMedia' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `chrome.*` APIs can only be used in extensions ([extensions API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index)) or apps ([apps API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index)).

The reason is that the API can be used to access private data and can do a lot of damage if used malevolently, so an explicit user consent is required to install an extension or app.

You can suggest the users to install an extension/app for your site using [inline installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation).

Comment: Thanks for the info @wOxxOm but can this be achieved by using some client side app like : nw.js ?

Comment: As you can see there's no desktopCapture in [the apps API index](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index), so an *extension* is required. As for the js library, there are no restrictions, use whatever you like and whatever works in the extension.

Comment: No, it is available for Chrome apps. See the sample: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/desktop-capture